# Servlet 3.0 and Comet/long-polling: What happens during these specific scenarios?

Tags: jquery, servlets, jakarta-ee, comet, long-polling

I took a look at a brief overview of Servlet 3.0's implementation of server push [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2009/jw-02-servlet3.html?page=3) and left with more questions than I came in with. The questions are related to my use case: implementing a dynamic notification system  amongst "friends", a la Facebook. Conceptually thinking about the problem, I would approach it as so:

1. Put an infinite jQuery loop in each
   page, containing code to issue an
   XMLHttpRequest "get" request to the
   server
2. Allow the server to store the
   request/response objects related to
   these type of XMLHttpRequests in an
   application-scoped map (with the
   help of AsyncContext and
   .startAsync()), keyed by the user's
   website ID
3. Whenever a user engages in an action
   that spawns notification, query the
   application-scoped map for IDs of
   the user's friends, and using the
   response objects stored there, send
   the notification to each friend.
4. Each of the friends receive the
   notification, and the infinite loop
   on the pages they're on issue
   XMLHttpRequests again (due to the infinite loop)

Assuming my system is conceptually sound (and if it isn't, please tell me what's wrong), there are a couple of issues that I see with this system:

1. What happens to a request/response
   pair in the map after the response
   is used? Am I supposed to manually
   delete it from the map, or wait for
   the loop on the client side to send
   another request so the stored
   request/response object pair can be
   replaced by the pair associated with
   the new XMLHttpRequest? The link
   above uses the words "committed" and
   "uncommitted" in reference to
   response objects. Can someone
   explain what those words mean in
   this context (I have a feeling
   they're related to the longevity of
   the response objects)?
2. What happens if two or more of a user's friends engage in actions that cause notifications at exactly the same time? There is only one request/response pair stored per user. Whichever friend's action happens to find the user in question's request/response pair gets its notification sent to that user, but what about the actions from the other friends? If they all happen at the same time, then the other actions won't have a request/response pair to use to send a notification until the user sends another XMLHttpRequest to be stored in the map. Presumably other actions will parse the map and either find no entry for that user (because its been manually deleted after the other action used the response), or find a "stale" request/response object that has already been used. I'm assuming that a response object can't be used for two different responses, so how would somebody go about rectifying this?
3. What happens if a notification is
   sent to a user when the user is
   switching pages? If we view a fully
   loaded web page as an open window
   for receiving notification requests,
   and a loading one as a closed window
   (because it is unable to receive and
   process responses to the
   XMLHttpRequests sent by the previous
   page), the notifications sent during
   this time frame will be lost. Is
   there anything I can do short of
   querying the database for new
   actions and generating notifications
   that way on page load?
4. Finally, what happen when a user
   navigates away from the site and the
   session expires? Are we expected to
   periodically iterate through the map
   and delete requests associated with
   no existing sessions?

Sorry if this was a long read. Even if you can only answer one of the above questions it would help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The response is kept until it times out probably. you keep pushing new info on it over and over again. That is what comet is. You don't loop get requests forever, you handle the data that is streaming from the server as it comes, 1 get request will last until it times out, then in the complete function issue another get.
2. Again, the response is still available, you are only writing on it, not closing it every time.
3. One way would be to timestamp all notifications and load the page with data from a certain time, your initial get request then provides the timestamp and you are then up to date.
4. I assume again, you hold it until it times out.

So just to better explain what is happening here,

- Your page is loaded and sends a get request.
- The request/response is stored in the map.
- Every update is then sent on the **SAME** request/response pair.
- Your get request listens for readystate === 3 (data received) and reads the data getting anything new that has been sent.
- When they timeout/have sent a certain amount of data/whatever they are removed.

Comment: Thanks! I took a look at the API for the asynchronous functionality and does appear to work that way. I got confused because Wikipedia says the following: "... The browser makes an asynchronous request of the server, which may wait for data to be available before responding...At the end of the processing of the response, the browser creates and sends another XHR, to await the next event...Thus the browser always keeps a request outstanding with the server, to be answered as each event occurs." A lot of the other material on the net define long-polling like this as well.

Comment: @Kevin, that is indeed what long polling is, what you describe in your question though is a different style of comet, called streaming, **not** long polling. I think that is where your confusion was stemming from.

Comment: Ah... for some reason I thought that servlet 3.0's implementation was long-polling only. It appears that it implements streaming by default and committing the response (via a call to complete()) in order to implement long-polling is optional.